# Which Pressure sensor in Netatmo weather station

Tags: sensors

I have been trying to figure out which barometric sensor that is being used in the Netatmo weather stations (netatmo.com/weather) to measure the atmospheric pressure. I have disassembled the indoor module (which measures the pressure), but I have not been able to find the relevant sensor. I know that the Bosch BMP280 is used in, e.g. iPhone 7. I have uploaded images of the main board to the following links, hoping that someone with more experience can identify the pressure sensor.

https://ibb.co/fdGPqL3
   https://ibb.co/FWSD58B
   https://ibb.co/M8hjsRR
   https://ibb.co/nRmBGPm
   https://ibb.co/rcL6Qpm
   https://ibb.co/qx3kgt0
   https://ibb.co/GcjzSBd
   https://ibb.co/4JpTDPq
   https://ibb.co/wQvPXX3
   https://ibb.co/vmyxY48
   https://ibb.co/k2LrwPG
   https://ibb.co/tXk57Bt
   https://ibb.co/711xYjW
   https://ibb.co/M5yy9W3
   https://ibb.co/QYDjXV2

Comment: Hey @Whir, perhaps you could pick the few most relevant images and upload them using the image tool (just click [edit]). This way it'll be uploaded to the site's image host and other users will see the images inline. I believe you're allowed up to 8 images/links as a new user which should be plenty.

Comment: looks like U7 has a hole in it, so that is most likely the one